# Solving of a first-order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help solving the following differential equation:

$$y'-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x\,\mathrm{e}^x}{y}=0$$

What should I do? If you could give me a hint then that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Although we know that ODEs will have (local) solutions, the sad truth is that most do not have "nice" solutions, i.e. that can be written down in terms of the elementary functions.

Your example has no nice solution. I have put it into both Maple and [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27-1/x-x%2aexp%28x%29/y=0), and neither are able to return a solution.

If you had some initial conditions, i.e. $y=1$ when $x=2$ then we you could find a power series approximation to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

$y'-\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{xe^x}{y}=0$

$y\dfrac{dy}{dx}-\dfrac{y}{x}=xe^x$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $x=e^t$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{e^t}=e^{-t}\dfrac{dy}{dt}$

$\therefore e^{-t}y\dfrac{dy}{dt}-e^{-t}y=e^te^{e^t}$

$y\dfrac{dy}{dt}-y=e^{2t}e^{e^t}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind in the canonical form.

Please follow the method in https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf